# Can't manage to collect the data - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener

First of, I'm a newbie at Javascript and React.js as you will probably observe. I'm currently trying to train myself.

I'm trying to display a "keyboard" (all letters from A to Z) and am trying to collect the data (the letter displayed) by implementing an onclick event on each letters.
However, even though my onclick event seems to be working, I'm getting an "undefined" answer in the console.

The handleLetterClicked() method is working fine but the handleKeyClicked() is not so I'm doing something wrong but can't get my head around it...

I hope you can help. thx in advance.

This is my keyboard component:

```
import React from 'react'
import './Keyboard.css'

const alphabet = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']


const displayKeyboard = alphabet.map((lettreAlphabet) =>
<div className="keyboardKey">    
    {lettreAlphabet}
</div>
)


const Keyboard = ({ lettreAlphabet, onClick }) => (
<div className={lettreAlphabet} onClick={() => onClick(lettreAlphabet)}>
    <span className="touche">
        {displayKeyboard}
        {lettreAlphabet}
    </span>
</div>
)


export default Keyboard
```

This is my app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import GuessCount from './GuessCount'
import Letter from './Letter'
import Keyboard from './Keyboard'

import './App.css' 

class App extends Component {

  handleKeyClicked(lettreAlphabet){
    console.log(lettreAlphabet, 'clicked')
  }
  handleLetterClicked(letter){
    console.log(letter, 'alsoClicked')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="pendu">
          <GuessCount guesses={0} />                
          <Letter letter="Z" feedback="visible" onClick={this.handleLetterClicked} />
        </div>
        <div className="keyboard">
          <Keyboard onClick={this.handleKeyClicked}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You invoke your `onClick` prop with the `lettreAlphabet` prop, but you are not giving the `Keyboard` component a `lettreAlphabet` prop, so it will be `undefined`.

Comment: Can you do me the favor and add `console.log(this.handleKeyClicked)` in the `render()` method? 
Seems like you did not bind the methods. But I'm wondering why `handleLetterClicked()` is working, then

Comment: @Neskews The methods are not using `this` so binding does not matter.

Comment: Tholle is right, however the deeper problem is that you're using a single prop for a Keyboard of 26 letters. You need to pass the App's `handleKeyClicked` down to `Keyboard`, then on to the individual letters. You can use the new context API for that. Or do it manually: https://codesandbox.io/s/nmjzz77ll

Comment: Wow thank you guys for your quick answers, will look into it asap!

Comment: It works! thanks a lot! I'm still learning and trying to understand all the vocabulary so the sandbox was perfect, now I get it!